# Radial filters/distortion in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to do this?

I want to create radial lines outwards.  A ripple filter creates circles within circles, but I would like lines coming out from the central point.

A good example of what I want to achieve would be the alternate flag of Japan:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Japan#mediaviewer/File:Naval_Ensign_of_Japan.svg
However unlike that flag I'd want all the lines to be an even width from center to outer edge.

I have CS5.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you just asking how to make lines in the form of a circle? Is this really something you cannot figure out on your own? They're lines... thick lines... in a circle. Did you try and it didn't look right or what's the challenge?

Comment: This question shows no effort. A Google search would most likely answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could achieve this easily By Adobe Illustrator, using rotate tool : make a copy for one time then remake the rotation via Control+D

Comment: Oh, awesome.  Should've thought of that.  Haha.  Thanks!  This is perfect.